# Python : unable to convert text to csv properly

Tags: python

Trying to convert a text file to csv but in the converted file I am getting square brackets at the start and end of each line and single quotes surrounding each character.

in the 1st step, I am trying to remove the single quotes, but this seems to be not working

the code is given below:

```
with open('New-file_0.csv','w') as p3:
    with open ('New-file_1','r') as p2: 
        for line in p2: 
            if not line.isspace(): 
                print(line.split(),file = p3)

with open ('final-file_1.csv','w') as p2:
    with open('New-file_0.csv','r') as p3: 
        for line in p3: 
            line=line.replace("'","") 
            print(line.split(),file = p2)
```

Comment: Please look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) module it is designed for reading and writing csv files. `line.split()` returns a `list` the string literal of a `list` is `[...]` - hence what you are seeing in your file.

Comment: This also does not seem to work as now I am getting some more braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're implicitly converting the split array to a string when printing it, which isn't formatting it the way you want. Use join to convert the array back to a comma-separated string.

```
print(",".join(line.split()), file=p2)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here:

1. Instead of printing to files, generally use `p3.write(myline)`.
2. `split()` generates lists, which you are currently giving to your print function, so they are written to your files. What you want to give them instead is a string, e.g. `",".join(line.split())`
3. Since in this case, you want to produce a .csv file, it would be better to circumvent all that and use the builtin csv module, which will take care of turning your list into a string:

   ```
   import csv

   with open(output_file,'wb') as p3: # make sure to use 'wb' for binary writing, or you will get unwanted empty rows
       output_data = csv.writer(p3, delimiter=",")
       with open (input_file,'r') as p2:
           for line in p2:
               row = line.strip().split()
               if row:
                   output_data.writerow(row)
   ```

(This module also allows reading of .csv files into a list of rows using `csv.read()`).

Comment: `line.split()` will always never be empty, because at a minimum `line == '\n'`. You would need to `line.strip().split()` to get an empty list for the `if row:` condition to be useful

Comment: @AChampion you're right, of course. Fixed my answer accordingly.